# how to group a character vector in R that contains a common character string?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing a column called `charge` containing a chracter vector and a column called `n` that is a numeric vector. The following data is a sample of what I have

```
charge<-c('unlawful possession of a firearm',
          'unlawful possession of a firearm repealed: 12-31-2016',
          'accessory unlawful possession of a firearm',
          'unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia',
          'unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia - prior drug offense',
          '579.074579.074579.074unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia')
n<-c(3904,4,2,2500,4,11)

df<-data.frame(charge,n)

                                                      charge    n
1                               unlawful possession of a firearm 3904
2          unlawful possession of a firearm repealed: 12-31-2016    4
3                     accessory unlawful possession of a firearm    2
4                      unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia 2500
5 unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia - prior drug offense    4
6 579.074579.074579.074unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia   11
```

As you can see the character vector has a bunch of charge codes that contain the two common phrases  ***unlawful possession of a firearm*** and ***unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia***. However I want to group these under the common phrases so that it looks like the following. how do I do this?

```
                       charge    n
1          unlawful possession of a firearm 3910
2 unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia 2515
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract part of the string with `str_extract`, use that as grouping variable and get the `sum` of 'n'.  Here the pattern used is the word 'unlawful' followed by space and other characters till we match either 'firearm' or 'drug paraphernalia'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(charge = str_extract(charge,
       "unlawful\\s+.*(firearm|drug paraphernalia)")) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  charge                                        n
#  <chr>                                     <dbl>
#1 unlawful possession of a firearm           3910
#2 unlawful possession of drug paraphernalia  2515
```